# how to swap the images by finger on touch

Tags: iphone

hi i am beginner in iphone programming,i am doing a project in which swapping along with zooming of the array of images to be done.. I had  searched in many websites, but still i didnt get a proper code to do it...

can anyone help me by giving any sample code or link...

thank you!!!

Comment: First of all, you need to ask real questions. This is not a question. Then, you need to describe your problem in more detail. What do you want to do ? Your "question" is so broad, it could mean anything and thus can't be answered. See: [How to ask questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of - I want some money!!! Pls send. Nice try.

Comment: You send me the buckz, I send you the codez

Comment: try three20. it's a iOS library used in facebook app

Answer (score 1):

You can try apple's sample code Photoscroller. It's nice sample code[link for code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080)